# Android - Global variables modifyed by clones

Tags: android, global-variables

I extended Application to store my global variables:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

    private ArrayList<Apk> applicazioni;

    public ArrayList<Apk> getApplicazioni() {
            return applicazioni;
    }

    public void setApplicazioni(ArrayList<Apk> applicazioni) {
            this.applicazioni = applicazioni;
    }
```

}

In the main activity i just did a local copy of "applicazioni":

```
MyApp oa = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
```

ArrayList apps=oa.getApplicazioni();

but if I remove one element from "apps", it disappear in "applicazioni" too!!
I want to modify my local copy and not the global variable, how I can do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
....
ArrayList apps = new ArrayList(oa.getApplicazioni());
....
```